# Imported Packages : com.day.cq.wcm.api,version=[1.29,2) and org.apache.sling.api.resource,version=[2.12,3) -- Cannot be resolved

Tags: osgi

I am facing a weird issue after creating the AEM project using the archetype 24 from https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-core-components/using/developing/archetype/overview.html?lang=en#available-properties

The project build successfully and deployed perfectly and somehow the osgi bundle is not "Active" because of below issue in bold: com.day.cq.wcm.api,version=[1.29,2) -- Cannot be resolved and org.apache.sling.api.resource,version=[2.12,3) -- Cannot be resolved

```
Imported Packages:

**com.day.cq.wcm.api,version=[1.29,2) -- Cannot be resolved**

**org.apache.sling.api.resource,version=[2.12,3) -- Cannot be resolved**
```

I have tried to add these dependencies in the parent pom finding in http://localhost:4502/system/console/depfinder

Somehow my efforts failed to resolve this issue, could anyone help me to resolve the issue.

thanks in advance

Comment: I found the resolution by adding the unresolved apis in the build section of the core pom file in the Import-packages as Import-Package: javax.annotation;version=0.0.0,com.day.cq.wcm.api;version=0.0.0,org.apache.sling.api.resource;version=0.0.0,*

Answer (score 1):

What you did to "solve" the issue is telling your bundle to accept any version of the packages. This very likely will cause problems later as you might get an incompatible implementation.

Instead what you should do is use the system console bundle view in AEM/sling to find out which versions of the packages are offered by the bundles. Probably the versions are lower than 1.29 and 2.12.

So the correct solution would be to use an older version of the archetype that matches the versions offered by your AEM/sling system.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with archetype 26.

resolved by adding this dependencies inside core/pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.day.cq.wcm/cq-wcm-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.day.cq.wcm</groupId>
    <artifactId>cq-wcm-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.api -->
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.api</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.4</version>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the language of the website to English and read the article here: https://flagtick.com/post/getting-started-with-aem-sites-setup-project-eduzone-system-part-7
It might help you a little bit.

```
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.apache.sling.caconfig.bnd-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```